# Prevent SQL injection in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I want to prevent SQL injection. It's a guild notice smp from a online game. The attacker used "`_)$*%RDELETE FROM Character WHERE sid >=1`". He deleted all our characters. (Backup ftw) But its really annoying to restore the backups again and again. And don't forget the little roll back with this. The smp seems fine to me. Yeah I'm a beginner so shame on me :*. Thank you for help.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[smp_set_guild_notice]
    @IN_GUILD_SID INT,
    @IN_NOTICE NVARCHAR(128)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (LEFT(@IN_NOTICE, 6) = '_)$*%R')
    BEGIN
        SET @IN_NOTICE = REPLACE(@IN_NOTICE,'_)$*%R','')
        EXEC sp_executesql @IN_NOTICE;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Guild 
        SET notice = @IN_NOTICE 
        WHERE sid = @IN_GUILD_SID
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the answer is obvious to anyone who understands SQL injection: don't `EXEC` untrusted input as an SQL statement!

I have no idea what the purpose of your `_)$*%R` prefix is. It appears to be a kind of "back-door" to allow a verbatim SQL statement to be executed? Why would you do this? Is it some kind of security-by-obscurity measure? The attacker was probably able to find out the prefix by looking at your web page source in their browser.

If this procedure is meant to update the guild notice, then just do the second UPDATE and remove the back-door code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[smp_set_guild_notice]
@IN_GUILD_SID   INT,
@IN_NOTICE      NVARCHAR(128)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE dbo.Guild SET notice = @IN_NOTICE WHERE sid = @IN_GUILD_SID
```

I'm not a Microsoft SQL Server developer, so that syntax might not be correct. I'm just showing what I mean by removing the part of the code that does the `EXEC`.

No SQL injection is possible when you hard-code your SQL, and use inputs only has value parameters.

Don't use `EXEC` if you can't sanitize input.

Comment: Ah god thank you! I cant upvote you sir :( but i give you the right anwser. Now i understand whats wrong with this code.